# Iterable Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch, callout, schedulebatch

I want to write a batch class and need to make a webservice callout from it. Once the response is returned in Json format. I want to process the same into objects of salesforce. So I know how to make a webservice callout and receive the response but not able to create a batch to call webservice callout function and process the response. Basically i need the approach or you can say placeholder structure which will help me understand how can i do it. Any help much appreciated.

```
public class GCPHelper {

public static void getGCPData(){

    HTTPResponse res = GCP_Utility.doHttpCall(gtoken.access_token, payLoad);
    String json =  res.getBody().replace('\n','');
    JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);

}
```

}

Comment: You seem to have already written a schedulable batch class, although you're doing work in the `start` method rather than the `execute()` method where it goes. It's not clear what you're seeking help with. Can you make your question specific?

Comment: @DavidReed I am new to batch class so just wondering how to write a right batch class for the schedulable class written.

Comment: It's not clear how to help you with your code architecture because right now your `GCPHelper` class basically does nothing. It performs no DML and does not iterate, so it doesn't clearly belong in a batch class. You've already written a schedulable batch. Your issue seems to be defining what work you're doing and how to perform that work in a bulkified manner. You'd need to add a lot more detail and specifics to your question for anyone to be able to help with that.

Comment: You might want to start with [Using Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch)

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question... why the downvotes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you need to get the data back to the batchable class so it can do something. This means returning some sort of iterable. That might look like this:

```
public class GCPHelper {
    public static JSON2Apex.results getGCPData(){

        HTTPResponse res = GCP_Utility.doHttpCall(gtoken.access_token, payLoad);
        String json =  res.getBody().replace('\n','');
        JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
        return obj.results;
    }
}
```

And in your batchable:

```
public JSON2Apex.results start(Database.batchableContext context) {
    return GCPhelper.getGCPData();
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, JSON2Apex.item) {
    // Do processing here
}
```

This is, of course, more pseudo-code, since we don't know what your response looks like, so you'll need to adjust data types as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

So your batch pattern could look something like this:

```
global class MyBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
  public static String jobStatus;

  global (Database.QueryLocator | Iterable<sObject>) start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
  }
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> records){
    // process each batch of records... up to 200 at a time
    String responseJSON = utilityClass.performHTTPCallout(List<sObject> records);//pass args, as needed, to your method where you perform your HTTP Callout.
    String jobStatus = utilityClass.processJSON(responseJSON);//perform your JSON deserialization and DML updates in this method
    //in practice I would combine the above into one method "performHTTPCallout" that returns void. Broke them out for the sake of illustration.
  }
  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    // execute any post-processing operations
    //e.g. if(jobStatus == 'fail'){...}
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.